# Simple Algebra question (fractions)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does $ \dfrac{-2}{2\sqrt{u}} $ equal $-\sqrt{u}$ or $-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u}}$

Comment: Perhaps the interesting thing here is to ask why would anyone think the square root in the denominator would/should/could "jump" to the numerator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{-2}{2\sqrt{u}} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{u}} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}$$